# Dropbox v2 web service to retrieve children of a folder is not returning "size" metadata for folders

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am integrating Dropbox in my application. I am able to retrieve child folders of a folder in Dropbox using "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder" web service. But the data that is being returned doesn't contain size data for folders. Is there any way to retrieve size data for folders in Dropbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't report the size of a folder. You would need to compute it yourself, presumably by using /list_folder (with `"recursive": true`). I'm assuming the definition you have in mind is "the sum of the sizes of all files contained within the folder, recursively."

Comment: Thanx for the answer.But they should have included the size field.Both Box and  one drive do that.